# C++ Pass global list to thread

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I'm currently using the Windows thread library. I want to pass a global list as an argument to one of my child threads and have it push to that list (allowing my main thread to access it).

Here's basically what I have:

```
std::list<SOCKET> mylist;
typedef struct {
  std::list<SOCKET>* listPtr;
  SOCKET listenSocket;
} buffer;

main_thread() {
  ... 
  Set up SOCKET socket = listen(...)
  ...

  buffer* buf = new buffer();
  buffer->listPtr = &mylist;
  buffer->listenSocket = socket;
  CreateThread(NULL, 0, child_thread, (void*)buffer, NULL, NULL);
}

child_thread(void* args) {
  buffer* buf = (buffer*) args;
  std::list<SOCKET> list = *(buf->listPtr);
  list.push_back(NULL);
}
```

The problem is after I mutate my list in the child thread, the main thread doesn't see any of these changes. I don't understand why not though, I'm passing the address of my global list into my child thread so anything I do to this list that I get in the child thread should be reflected in my global list, correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating a copy of the list here:

```
std::list<SOCKET> list = *(buf->listPtr);
```

Try this instead

```
std::list<SOCKET> *list = buf->listPtr;
list->push_back(NULL);
```

Comment: Huh ok that works. Thanks! Why does the first way of doing it create a copy?

Comment: @xhassassin: Because it declares `list` to be an object, initialised by copying another list.